# Docusign for Salesforce template - Show merge fields to all roles

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to setup a template using Docusign for Salesforce. My template is 20 page long and has about 50 merge fields to be populated from Saleforce. These merge fields are read only. We have multiple signer roles - 6 signer roles to be specific. In the template, all 6 signer roles should see all the merge fields.

Problem is when these merge fields are added to template by drag and drop, you have to select a single role and then drag and drop a field on template.

Is there a way to prepare a template so that merge field display on the template can be added for all roles in a single go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docusign support was able to resolve the question.

We need to edit the tags after they are added to the template. Click on each tag and go to Collaboration and check the box to "Recipients Can Collaborate.